# Trello Auto Send Email to Cards

Tags: trello, email

Can Trello be set up to automatically send emails from certain email addresses directly to client's card?

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this with a combination of Trello's card-specific emails and email filtering/forwarding or [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com).

First, grab the email address for the card you want to add comments to. [You'll find this under "Share and More" on the back of the card.](https://trello.com/c/78YYOczz)

Depending on your email provider, there are various ways to forward emails based on a rule or filter. Basically, you want to look for all emails from those certain addresses and forward them to the card's email address.

If you're using Gmail, here's an example using IFTTT:

- Create a new recipe that starts with the Gmail "[New email in inbox from](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/triggers/86-new-email-in-inbox-from)" trigger
- Enter the email address of the sender whose emails you want to send directly to Trello
- Now choose the Gmail "[Send an email](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/actions/34-send-an-email)" action
- Enter the card's email address as the To address
- Fill in the subject, body, and attachment URL with the info from the trigger

If you're using Outlook/Exchange, here's an example using inbox rules:

- Create a new inbox rule
- For "When the message arrives, and" choose "It was received from..." and enter the email address(es) whose emails you want to send directly to Trello
- For "Do the following" choose "Forward the message to..." and enter the card's email address

It's the same concept, just two different ways of implementing it.